# How to Create UITabBarController via interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a view controller which is my rootviewcontroller i.e LoginviewController .On button click from loginviewcontroller i wanted to go to tabbarcontroller please let me now that how can i created tabbar controller on button click from loginviewcontoller via interface builder only not with storyboard nor programmatically. I am using xcode 4.5.2 and sdk 6

Answer (score 1):

Inside Application did finish launching add

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  LogInVC *LoginVCObj = [[LogInVC alloc] init withNibNamed:"LogInVC" bundle:nil]; 
  LoginVCObj.delegate = self;
  [window LoginVCObj.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

// when logs in successfully
- (void)logInSuccessfully 
{
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[MyFirstVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFirstVC" bundle:nil]; 
 UIViewController *viewController2 = [[MySecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySecondVC" bundle:nil]; 
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```

Comment: the error is that property delegate not found on object of type LoginVC

Comment: you can comment that line but not forget to call - (void)logInSuccessfully  method by urself ...

Comment: its off no use the app is not going anywhere on button click

Comment: i have added logininSuccessfully method code on button click of by loginviewcontroller

Comment: [window addSubView:LoginVCObj.view];

Answer (score 0):

After successful login, you can redirect that to custom tabbar.
You can see the steps for custom tabbar in this [link](http://kurrytran.blogspot.in/2011/10/ios-5-tutorial-creating-custom-tab-bar.html)

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Smriti Yadav i want to make it via xib not via storyboard as mentioned in the question.